# Read aloud (text-to-speech) a PDF file?

Tags: windows, pdf, speech-synthesis

(I have already asked [this question on Ebooks SE](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/6635/what-is-the-best-way-to-read-aloud-text-to-speech-a-pdf-file), but as I received no response, I thought this site might be a better place to ask it.)

I really like the Adobe Reader Read Aloud tool. I listen to it and at the same time read the words that are being narrated. It helps me to focus on the article and reduces my attention to distractions. However, in some PDF files, it reads them word by word. I mean I have to click the next word to read and it does not identify paragraphs correctly.
Also, when I try to copy the text from Adobe Reader to Microsoft Word to use Microsoft Narrator, it does not copy "fi"s. For example, the word "defined" will be copied as "de ned."

Do you know any better text-to-speech software? Or do you know how to solve these issues?